# Jquery Selectors for name prefixes in division

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

In my HTML code I have buttons 1, 2, 3 and 4 for 4 different views. I have some divs named as:

```
sheet(button id)+some string
```

So whenever I click on button 2 suppose, I want all the divisions with `id=sheet2abc`, `id=sheet2xyz`, etc to become visible and for the rest (i.e. 1, 3 and 4) the `dispaly:none` property should be set like for `sheet1abc`, `sheet3abc`, etc.

How can I do this via jQuery selectors?

Comment: Can you show us what you already have tried?

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to use wildcards in jQuery selectors.

This shows every `div` whose `id` starts with "sheet1":

```
$('div[id^=sheet1]').each(function() {
    $(this).show();
});
```

And this hides the others:

```
$('div[id^=sheet]:not([id^=sheet1])').each(function() {
    $(this).hide();
});
```

I created [a fiddle to demonstrate that](http://jsfiddle.net/alp82/KgXSN/).

Answer (score 2):

KISS. Essentially:

```
$('[id^=sheet]').hide();
$('[id^=sheet'+num+']').show(); // num is a relevant value, see the example
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/j4TzA/

Comment: @Davin - Can you please help with this one as well?

Comment: @Rohan, derek gave you a good answer. Check out my updated example: http://jsfiddle.net/j4TzA/1/

Comment: sorry,I saw the fiddle.. wrote the comment by mistake!

Comment: @Rohan, the new example I gave you in my comment answers your second question (about containing a div) as well as this one, together.

Answer (score 1):

Buttons: `<a href="1" class="button">button 1</a>` and so on

Sheets: `<div id="sheet1" class="sheet">sheet 1</div>` and so on

jQuery:

```
$('.button').click(function(event){

    event.preventDefault();

    $('.sheet').hide();
    $('#sheet'+$(this).attr('href')).show();

}
```

Next time make your question more clear.

Comment: this is not the right solution because it does only address divs with the exact name you provided.

Answer (score 1):

You can filter like:

```
$('button').click(function() {
    var $button = $(this);
    $('div[id^=sheet]').each(function() {
        if((new RegExp("^sheet" + $button.data('id') + ".*$")).test($(this).attr('id'))) {
            $(this).show();
        } else {
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Then code buttons like:

```
<button data-id="1">1</button>
```